# I Need Help To Check A Script In

Tags: autoit

I Got A Problem With A Simple Login Gui In Autoit And I Really Cant Find Out Why It Wont Print The Username And Pass To A Text File

Here's The Code:

```
$gui = GuiCreate("Authenticate",120,170)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Username:",10,10,50,20)
$username = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,35,100,20)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password:",10,70,50,20)
$password = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,95,100,20,0x0020)

$go = GuiCtrlCreateButton("OK",10,130,50,25)
$cancel = GuiCtrlCreateButton("Cancel",60,130,50,25)

GUISetState()
Do
$msg = GUIGetMsg()

If $msg = $go Then

   FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\userout.txt', $username)
   FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\passout.txt', $password)
   Run("confirm.bat", "", @SW_HIDE)

EndIf

If $msg = $cancel Then
Exit
EndIf

Until GUIGetMsg() = $cancel
GuiDelete($gui)
```

I Tried To Use Different Lines Of Code But I Cant Find The Problem.
Thanks Beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to read out the controls. In your script, you get the value of the control-id only.

```
$gui = GuiCreate("Authenticate",120,170)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Username:",10,10,50,20)
$username = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,35,100,20)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password:",10,70,50,20)
$password = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,95,100,20,0x0020)

$go = GuiCtrlCreateButton("OK",10,130,50,25)
$cancel = GuiCtrlCreateButton("Cancel",60,130,50,25)

GUISetState()
Do
$msg = GUIGetMsg()

If $msg = $go Then

   ; FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\userout.txt', $username)  ; wrong
   FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\userout.txt', GUICtrlRead($username))  ; correct
   ; FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\passout.txt', $password)  ; wrong
   FileWrite(@ScriptDir & '\passout.txt', GUICtrlRead($password))  ; correct
   Run("confirm.bat", "", @SW_HIDE)

EndIf

If $msg = $cancel Then
Exit
EndIf

Until GUIGetMsg() = $cancel
GuiDelete($gui)
```